# Spark EC2 Connection refused

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop2

I'm getting the 'connection refused' exception running Spark code.
I'm running on an Amazon AWS EC2 instance.
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Hadoop is configured use port 8020.

Port 8020 is bound to localhost 127.0.0.1.  I was told this is a problem.

How should /etc/hosts be configured?

```
ubuntu@ec2-52-8-16-250:~$ netstat -atnp | grep 8020
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8020          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38730         127.0.0.1:8020          TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38683         127.0.0.1:8020          ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8020          127.0.0.1:38683         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38732         127.0.0.1:8020          ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8020          127.0.0.1:38732         ESTABLISHED -               
ubuntu@ec2-52-8-16-250:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
10.0.1.215 ec2-52-8-16-250.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com ec2-52-8-16-250

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
ubuntu@ec2-52-8-16-250:~$
```

core-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/hadoop/tmp</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
</property>
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>1</value>
 </property>
 <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
      <value>file:/bigdata/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
      <value>file:/bigdata/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/datanode</value>
 </property>
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
<value>localhost:50090</value>
</property>


$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.6.4
Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 5082c73637530b0b7e115f9625ed7fac69f937e6
Compiled by jenkins on 2016-02-12T09:45Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 8dee2286ecdbbbc930a6c87b65cbc010
This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.4.jar
hduser@ip-10-0-1-215:/home/ubuntu$ 

hduser@ip-10-0-1-215:/home/ubuntu$ env | grep HADOOP
HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native
HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
HADOOP_OPTS=-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native
HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
```

Hadoop processes:

```
hduser@ip-10-0-1-215:/home/ubuntu$ jps
22082 DataNode
22306 SecondaryNameNode
22519 NodeManager
22471 ResourceManager
21902 NameNode
23198 Jps
22959 JobHistoryServer
```

E.g.

```
$ hduser@ip-10-0-1-215:/home/ubuntu$ hadoop fs -put /hdfs/wikidump.xml /user/hduser/wikidump.xml
$ hduser@ip-10-0-1-215:/home/ubuntu$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hduser
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup 52927948149 2016-07-26 19:43 /user/hduser/wikidump.xml

hduser@ip-10-0-1-215:/home/ubuntu$ nc -vz localhost 8020
Connection to localhost 8020 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-215:/usr/local/hadoop/logs$ nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-07-27 02:37 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00060s latency).
Not shown: 991 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
22/tcp   open  ssh
631/tcp  open  ipp
5902/tcp open  vnc-2
6002/tcp open  X11:2
8031/tcp open  unknown
8042/tcp open  fs-agent
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
8088/tcp open  radan-http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-215:/usr/local/hadoop/logs$ nmap 52.8.16.250

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-07-27 02:38 UTC
Nmap scan report for ec2-52-8-16-250.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com (52.8.16.250)
Host is up (0.00056s latency).
Not shown: 983 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
20/tcp   closed ftp-data
21/tcp   open   ftp
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   closed http
443/tcp  closed https
3030/tcp closed arepa-cas
5000/tcp closed upnp
5222/tcp closed xmpp-client
5432/tcp closed postgresql
5901/tcp closed vnc-1
5902/tcp open   vnc-2
5903/tcp closed vnc-3
5904/tcp closed unknown
8080/tcp open   http-proxy
8081/tcp closed blackice-icecap
8888/tcp closed sun-answerbook
9000/tcp closed cslistener

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.46 seconds

Nmap scan report for ip-10-0-1-215.us-west-1.compute.internal (10.0.1.215)
Host is up (0.00051s latency).
Not shown: 992 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
22/tcp   open  ssh
5902/tcp open  vnc-2
6002/tcp open  X11:2
8031/tcp open  unknown
8042/tcp open  fs-agent
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
8088/tcp open  radan-http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-215:/usr/local/hadoop/logs$ 

$ ~/spark/bin/spark-shell -version

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Using Spark's repl log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults-repl.properties
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel("INFO")
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.2
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_101)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
16/07/27 03:00:49 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
Spark context available as sc.
SQL context available as sqlContext.
```

Here's the full stack trace:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Call From ip-10-0-1-215.us-west-1.compute.internal/10.0.1.215 to 52.8.16.250:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:752)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1988)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1644)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:292)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:385)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PartitionwiseSampledRDD.getPartitions(PartitionwiseSampledRDD.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$zipWithUniqueId$1.apply(RDD.scala:1286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$zipWithUniqueId$1.apply(RDD.scala:1285)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.zipWithUniqueId(RDD.scala:1285)
    at com.cloudera.datascience.lsa.ParseWikipedia$.documentTermMatrix(ParseWikipedia.scala:48)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$RunLSA$.preprocessing(<console>:111)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:71)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:80)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:82)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:84)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:86)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:88)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:90)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:92)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:94)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:96)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:98)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:100)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:102)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:104)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:106)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:108)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:110)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:112)
    at <init>(<console>:114)
    at .<init>(<console>:118)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:704)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpretInput(SparkInterpreter.java:912)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:858)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:851)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:94)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:383)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:176)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
    ... 127 more
ERROR   

%spark 
 val numTerms = 50000
    val sampleSize =  0.1
     val (termDocMatrix, termIds, docIds, idfs) = RunLSA.preprocessing(sampleSize, numTerms, sc)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$zipWithUniqueId$1.apply(RDD.scala:1286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$zipWithUniqueId$1.apply(RDD.scala:1285)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.zipWithUniqueId(RDD.scala:1285)
    at com.cloudera.datascience.lsa.ParseWikipedia$.documentTermMatrix(ParseWikipedia.scala:48)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$RunLSA$.preprocessing(<console>:111)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:71)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:80)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:82)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:84)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:86)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:88)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:90)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:92)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:94)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:96)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:98)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:100)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:102)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:104)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:106)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:108)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:110)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:112)
    at <init>(<console>:114)
    at .<init>(<console>:118)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:704)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpretInput(SparkInterpreter.java:912)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:858)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:851)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:94)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:383)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:176)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
    ... 127 more
```

Comment: Why do you have services only listening on localhost? That's why you can't connect

Comment: So: <property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
</property>
should be: <property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020</value>
</property>

Comment: Considering that that property is deprecated... No. You can see here what the defaults and explanations are.  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml

Comment: And here's hdfs site, if you need it.  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml

Answer (score 0):

Editing /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml use 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost solved the problem:

`<property> <name>fs.default.name</name> <value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020</value> </property>`